# Add Column to Pandas DataFrame Not in Place

Tags: pandas

How do I add a Series as a new column to a Pandas DataFrame and get back a new DataFrame (i.e NOT in place).

This works, but is in place:

```
A["name"] = s
```

Answer (score 20):

From `0.16.0` onwards, you can use `assign` -- returns a new object (a copy) with all the original columns in addition to the new ones.

```
In [483]: A.assign(name=s)
Out[483]:
          0         1  name
0  0.876880  0.915174     0
1  0.644664  0.305387     1
2  0.930093  0.562453     2
3  0.807626  0.498871     3
```

Details

```
In [484]: A
Out[484]:
          0         1
0  0.876880  0.915174
1  0.644664  0.305387
2  0.930093  0.562453
3  0.807626  0.498871

In [485]: s
Out[485]:
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 6):

Not sure whether there's any more elegant way, but this works to me:

```
df = pd.concat( [A, pd.DataFrame(s)], axis=1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

If `A` is your DataFrame and `s` is the series.

```
df2 = A.copy()
df2['name'] = s
```